# Javascript, changing object value

Tags: javascript, google-maps

It's pretty hard to explain so I'll just show an example.

```
for(i=1;i<position.length;i++)
        {   
            if(position[i].lat() == position[i-1].lat() && position[i].lng() == position[i-1].lng())
            {

                position[i].lat = position[i].lat() + ((Math.random() -.5) / 1500);
                position[i].lng = position[i].lng() + ((Math.random() -.5) / 1500);
                //position[i].lng = position[i].lng() + ((Math.random() -.5) / 1500);
                //console.log(position[i].lat().value);
            }
        }
```

Basically I'm trying to just change the value of lat and lng in the position array but I can't seem to find a solution.

```
 $('#data').find('div[name=postalCode]').each(function(i) {
            var latlng = $(this).find('input[type=hidden]');
            position.push(new google.maps.LatLng(latlng[0].value, latlng[1].value));
            });
```

And this is how the position array is filled up.

Any help is appreciated. thanks
Realize that the above comparison code does not fully compare, i'll put the new code here just in case anyone uses it

```
for (var i = 0; i < position.length; i++) {
            for(var k = i+1; k<position.length; k++){
        if (position[i].lat() == position[k].lat() && (position[i].lng() == position[k].lng())) {
            console.log("before change" + i + position[i].lat());
           position[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(
        position[i].lat() + ((Math.random() * 1.5) / 100),
        position[i].lng() + ((Math.random() * 1.5) / 100)
        );
        console.log("after change" +i + position[i].lat());
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is `lat` and `lng` a property or function on your array? You're calling them both ways.

Comment: What about removing `()` at the end of `lat` and `lng`.

Comment: Hi, I edited the post to show how position[] gets its data.

Comment: still. `lat()` means you are calling a function. but it is not  a function. Remove the `()`

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference   
_"Notice that you cannot modify the coordinates of a LatLng. If you want to compute another point, you have to create a new one."_   
In short, don't change the values, **replace the entry**.

Comment: Is position array of google map markers? or just json object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference

*"Notice that you cannot modify the coordinates of a LatLng. If you want to compute another point, you have to create a new one."*

In short, don't change the values, **replace the entry**.

Example:

```
for (var i = 1; i < position.length; i++) {
    if (position[i].lat() == position[i - 1].lat() && position[i].lng() == position[i - 1].lng()) {
        position[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(
            position[i].lat() + ((Math.random() - .5) / 1500),
            position[i].lng() + ((Math.random() - .5) / 1500)
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help, didn't know that i was just going in a wrong direction the whole time.